# When do these ODE have positive solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Consider the ODE \begin{equation} x'' + q(t) x = 0 \end{equation} in the unit interval $(0,1)$, with a potential function $q(t) = 4\pi^2 - \frac{Ct}{(1 - t)^2}$ depending on a positive constant $C > 0$.

> Can you estimate the critical value $C_0$ which ensures that for $C > C_0$, the solution to the ODE with $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 1$ is strictly positive in $(0,1)$? I am mainly looking for a 'good' upper bound for $C_0$, and I would be most curious about arguments that could also apply to similar potential functions, such as in (1).

As I see it, the terms $4 \pi^2$ and $-C/(1 - t)^2$ are competing in the ODE, with the first making solutions oscillate, and the second forcing exponential divergence or decay. My question is how to determine the critical value of $C$ above which the second part dominates.

*Comments.* (1) Alexandre Eremenko is right to point out in the comments that there is a trade-off. To know the precise value of $C_0$, one needs to solve the equation exactly. I would be more interested in a robust argument, which would give a 'reasonable' approximation of $C_0$, but would also be flexible enough to apply to similar potentials, say if for $a,b > 0$
\begin{equation}
q(t) = a - b \tan(t)
\quad
\text{or}
\quad
q(t) = a - b t^{1/2} / (1 - t)^2.
\end{equation}

(2) Below is my attempt at reducing the ODE to the Bessel equation, using Kamke's book as a reference. I haven't been successful, but I've also become somewhat skeptical about the strategy. This is because, assuming the solution $x$ is expressed as some combination of Bessel functions, one would be left with the task of deducing an estimate for $C_0$. I am not sure whether this would be easier than trying to bound $C_0$ directly.

If you clear the denominators, and make the change of variable $s = t - 1$, this turns into the equation
\begin{equation}
s^2 y'' + (4 \pi^2 s^2 - Cs - C) y = 0.
\end{equation}
If one further sets $y = s \eta$, then the equation becomes
\begin{equation}
s^2 \eta'' + 2 s \eta' + (4 \pi^2 s^2 - C s - C) \eta.
\end{equation}
However, I haven't completely figured out how to express its solution in terms of the Bessel functions, much less obtain a reasonable value for $C_0$ for this.

Comment: Your ODE can be reduced to the Bessel eq. by a simple change of the variable, and the answer can be obtained in terms of zeros of a Bessel function. (See, for example Kamke, 2.273 (6)).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thanks, I'll try to work this out! If it couldn't be brought to a Bessel equation, say because the potential is $q(t) = 4 \pi^2 - C \tan(2t/\pi)$ or $q(t) = 4 \pi^2 - C \sqrt{t}/(1 - t)^2$ instead, then you would compare it to the equation above and apply some Sturm comparison theorem? Would that be the standard approach?

Comment: You are asking "what is the value of $C_0$..." presumably meaning some exact value with a closed form expression. Sturm and other such arguments cannot give you this. You can expect an exact value only for an equation which is exactly solvable, like Bessel, or other such equation defining special functions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko You're right, that was a bit unclear. I've amended the wording of the question to better explain what I am looking for. Basically I'm hoping for an upper bound for $C_0$, because I want to ensure that the solutions do not change sign. An argument that goes via the exact computation of the solutions would be fine, but ideally there might be some method that gives an 'OK' upper bound, and that might apply also to other, similar forms of the potential.